# How do I control the processing time when you do sort or page in jquery DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a question in jQuery Datatables. This "Processing" message shows everytime when I click sort, and the sort is client side sorting. it is really annoying because it looks like a flickering. How can I do something like this? If the processing time is less than 1 sec, do not show "Processing" message?

```
$('#tblUsers').dataTable({
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "sProcessing": false,
                    "sAjaxSource": path,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "iDisplayLength": 15,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "aoColumns":
                [
                    { "mDataProp": "UserName" },
                    { "mDataProp": "FirstName" },
                    { "mDataProp": "LastName" },
                    { "sDefaultContent": "", "fnRender": function (oObj) { return "<a onclick=AssignUser(this,'" + oObj.aData.UserName + "','btnRemove_" + oObj.aData.UserName + "') id='btnAssgin_" + oObj.aData.UserName + "'> Assign User</a>"; }
                    },
                     { "sDefaultContent": "", "fnRender": function (oObj) { return "<a onclick=RemoveUser(this,'" + oObj.aData.UserName + "','btnAssgin_" + oObj.aData.UserName + "') id='btnRemove_" + oObj.aData.UserName + "' disabled='true'>Remove User</a>"; }
                     }

                ],
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                                      { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [0] },
                                      { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [1] },
                                      { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [2] },
                                      { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [3] },
                                      { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [4] }
                                    ]
                });
```

Comment: isn't the point of the "Processing" message to indicate that `something` is still going on? How would you know how long `something` is going to take, before it finishes?

Comment: right, But it is too often. I wonder if I can do this, if process is taking less than 1 sec, dont show the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see the Processing indicator, just set `bProcessing` to false (or remove it altogether, which makes it false by default). If you didn't want to see it, not sure why you included `bProcessing` to start with! Inherited the code?

[update in response to comment]

I understand now. But I think it's a red herring, and it comes back to kaveman's comment. You don't know how long processing is going to take until it's done.

"But Greg!" I hear some of you saying, "Just don't show that Processing thing until it's been at least a second long! Easy!"

All you would do is trade off one problem for a delayed version of the same problem. Let's say the processing takes 1.2 seconds. You wait to show the "processing" indicator for a second, then you decide "Yup, this is a long one, let's show the indicator!" But then the indicator only shows for 0.2 seconds. An ugly "flash", just delayed longer. In fact, I would argue that in this case, it would have looked better if it was just visible the whole time.

I don't see a good way to solve this unless you can always predict with relative certainty how long the process should take. And you can't do that because every client-side environment is going to be different.

I recommend not trying to catch this red herring... either keep it enabled or don't. That's my honest advice.

Comment: I want to see the processing indicator. BUT I dont want to see this too often. for example, if the process is less than 1 sec, dont show the "processing" message.

Comment: Updated answer in response to comment.